# Ubuntu shows that it's connected to wifi, but will not load any pages

Tags: 14.04, wireless

Whenever I start firefox, none of the pages will load, even though it is connected to my home wifi.

Comment: Do you have a virtual machine or it's your Host OS

Comment: It is my host OS.

Comment: Sorry i only have VM....i just change my MAC address and it fixes the problem

Comment: What does `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8 && ping -c 4 google.com` tell us ?

Comment: All that it tells me when I type in these commands is ping's usage.

Comment: @GradonHutchinson please post the output of the ping commands. if they aren't running, please double check that you've copy pasted correctly.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-
what-can-i-do>